# How to pass date format to API using gte and lte using MongoDb from frontend angular?

Tags: angular, mongodb

My requirement is to pass date parameters to API, backend used is MongoDB, I am trying pass date parameters from angular using like this:

```
this.payload.criteria = {
 "createdAt": { "$gte": moment('08-01-2021').toDate() }
}
```

Records exists of 08-01-2021 still I am getting empty response as this []

Tried passing something like this:

```
var newdate = new Date("2021-01-07T09:27:08.433+00:00")

this.payload.criteria = {
 "createdAt": { "$gte": newdate }
 
}
```

Nothing works, any clue what is the correct format?

Comment: please, add sample document from your collection or at least for the "createdAt"  field

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var newdate = new Date("2021-01-07T09:27:08.433+00:00")
new
this.payload.criteria = {
 "createdAt": { "$gte": newdate.toISOString() }
}
```